how to calculate the RMSE between the keypoints and their transformed in ORB algorithm in image registration
I calculated the RMSE between the keypoints of the reference image and the sensed image using the ORB algorithm for image registration. Despite the transformation parameters being close to the ground truth and the accuracy appearing good, the RMSE value is still high.
Is there any guidance on how to correctly calculate RMSE in feature-based image registration?
my code is
    pt1=kp1[inliers_idxs]
    points1=np.hstack((pt1,np.ones((pt.shape[0],1))))
    points = np.hstack((pt,np.ones((pt.shape[0],1))))
    transformed_points_homogeneous = model_robust@points.T
    rmse=np.sqrt(np.sum((transformed_points_homogeneous[:2,:].T-pt1)**2,axis=1).mean()))`


